# Is there a name for this representation of data?

Tags: data-structures

Suppose you have data for which a normalized view would be something like

```
ID   First Name      Last Name   Height   
--   ----------      ---------   ------
1      Ann             Jones      63
2      John            Smith      72
```

But the data comes to us in this representation:

```
ID    Type         Value
--    ----         ----- 
1    'FirstName'   Ann   
1    'LastName'    Jones
1    'Height'      63
2    'FirstName'   John
2    'LastName'    Smith
2    'Height'      72
```

It's sort of a normalized table turned sideways, or an "unpivoted" table.

My question is:  is there a NAME for this kind of representation -- these 'ID, Type, Value' triples?  (In reality the Type is an integer and maps to a type table, but I made it a string to make it clearer what it represented.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose this could be considered as close to the [**EAV (Entity-Attribute-Value) Model**](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model)

Except you only have the two following tables :

- `Entity`
- `Value`

And no `Attribute` table.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was thinking of!